# What is the external force during rebound of a ball?

Tags: momentum, energy-conservation

Consider the situation when a ball hits a plane surface at an angle of incidence $\theta$ with speed $u$ and rebounds with the same angle. One can notice that there is a change in momentum in this scenario but I can't seem to find out what is the external force here? The ball exerts a force on the surface and by Newton's 3rd law, an equal and opposite force is exerted by the surface on the ball. These are all internal forces in the "plane surface + ball" system.

So what force is causing the change in momentum?

Comment: The plane definitively exerts a force on the ball or what other force are you looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is friction, since the wall is attached to the floor. In an ideal system, the ball would also move the wall in the opposite direction with little speed, depending on the ratios of their masses. Also note that if you look from a larger perspective, say, take the whole planet as a system, you can justify momentum still being conserved as the ball and the wall are both on Earth.

Comment: I understood about the friction that prevents the wall from moving. However, could you elaborate on why momentum would remain conserved when Earth is taken as the system?

Comment: Is it because the friction also acts on the Earth and causes an equal change in momentum of the Earth?

Comment: No, if you are on Earth, you can't change Earth's momentum, think of it in steps: First you throw the ball to the wall, when you do, the ball pushes you back, you push the ground back, giving an impulse to the planet, then the ball hits the wall, (and air molecules before that as well, to be accurate) and it gives the momentum you gave to the ball, to the wall. The wall then gives an impulse to the planet, which will be opposite the impulse you gave it when you first threw! So the sum of the chain of events will always end up with a 0 change for momentum.

Comment: Instead of a planet, it is easier to picture for an object like the space station. If you jump from the floor towards the ceiling in the space station, while you are in between the two surfaces you have a certain momentum up, and the space station has the same momentum down. When you hit the ceiling, you stop, and you give your momentum to the space station upwards, which cancels out the intial momentum it had downwards from your jump. That's what is meant by "internal forces", ultimately momentum doesn't change.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a force exerted on the surface to counteract the force the ball exerts on it since the surface does not accelerate. This is provided by whatever the surface is connected to - if it's sitting on a table, then it's the table, if it's attached to a wall, then it's the wall. As you are considering the system to be the surface + ball, those would be external forces.